# Tensorflow- bidirectional_dynamic_rnn: Attempt to reuse RNNCell

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, tensorflow

The following code (taken from - https://github.com/dennybritz/tf-rnn/blob/master/bidirectional_rnn.ipynb)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.reset_default_graph()

# Create input data
X = np.random.randn(2, 10, 8)

# The second example is of length 6 
X[1,6:] = 0
X_lengths = [10, 6]

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=64, state_is_tuple=True)

outputs, states  = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(
    cell_fw=cell,
    cell_bw=cell,
    dtype=tf.float64,
    sequence_length=X_lengths,
    inputs=X)

output_fw, output_bw = outputs
states_fw, states_bw = states
```

**is giving the following error for**

> tensorflow - 1.1 for both 2.7 and 3.5

```
ValueError: Attempt to reuse RNNCell <tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.core_rnn_cell_impl.LSTMCell object at 0x10ce0c2b0> 
with a different variable scope than its first use.  First use of cell was with scope 
'bidirectional_rnn/fw/lstm_cell', this attempt is with scope 'bidirectional_rnn/bw/lstm_cell'.  
Please create a new instance of the cell if you would like it to use a different set of weights.  
If before you were using: MultiRNNCell([LSTMCell(...)] * num_layers), change to:
 MultiRNNCell([LSTMCell(...) for _ in range(num_layers)]).  If before you were using the same cell 
 instance as both the forward and reverse cell of a bidirectional RNN, simply create two instances 
 (one for forward, one for reverse).  In May 2017, we will start transitioning this cell's behavior to use 
 existing stored weights, if any, when it is called with scope=None (which can lead to silent model degradation, 
 so this error will remain until then.)
```

**But it is working in**

> tensorflow - 1.0.1 for python 3.5 (did not test on python - 2.7)

I tried with multiple code examples I found online but

> tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn
> is giving the same error with tensorflow - 1.1

Is there a bug in tensorflow 1.1 or am i just missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry you ran into this. I can confirm that the error appears in 1.1 (`docker run -it  gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:1.1.0 python`) but not in 1.2 RC0 (`docker run -it  gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:1.2.0-rc0 python`).

So it looks like either 1.2-rc0 or 1.0.1 are your options for the moment.

Comment: is there a way currently to install 1.2 on mac from pip? I tried the installing **tensorflow-1.2.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl** form [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow) but i got `tensorflow-1.2.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: Which version of Python? That package should work with 3.5.

Comment: for me 
`python --version
Python 3.5.3`
on conda created environment on mac.
The command I am running - `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade ~/Downloads/tensorflow-1.2.0rc0-cp35-cp35m-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl`

Comment: And `pip --version` tells you that it's referencing 3.5 too?

Comment: `pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /Users/shoubhik/anaconda/envs/py35-tf1.1/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)`

Comment: I guess it has to be the OSX version, then? I think it's just matching based on the filenamename and your system specs/python version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144969/discussion-between-shoubhik-and-allen-lavoie).